# Why does Visual Studio (2010) run two builds for a BizTalk Server Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, biztalk

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and BizTalk 2010.
When I add a new `Empty BizTalk Server Project` and build it, I get the following output:

```
------ Build started: Project: ThrowAway1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  ThrowAway1 -> c:\...\Projects\ThrowAway1\ThrowAway1\bin\Debug\ThrowAway1.dll
  ThrowAway1 -> c:\...\Projects\ThrowAway1\ThrowAway1\bin\Debug\ThrowAway1.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I already tried deactivating the release build. But I still get two build events - which also affects the post build event.
With a default console application I get only one build event.

My goal is to run my own deployment PowerShell script in the post build event. The script is coming along nicely but it is called two times by this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the expected behavior of a BizTalk Project.

I'm only speculating that it's because many BizTalk artifacts are compiled in a two step process.  Orchestrations to C# then C# to the output Assembly for example.

The only thing I can recommend is to either make the script deterministic or maybe a side project that runs the post build for the entire Solution.

You can also investigate the BizTalk Deployment Framework: http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! Good hints. Did not know about the necessity for the two step compilation.

Answer (score 0):

As a pragmatic solution:
Checking the .btproj MSBuild file and its imports

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkC.targets" />
```

where `BizTalkC.targets` imports

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\BizTalk\BizTalkCommon.targets" />
```

shows the usage of `$(SecondBuild)` in `BizTalkCommon.targets`.

This can be used in the post build event:

```
if "$(SecondBuild)"=="true" (
  rem Run script.
)
```

For the first build `$(SecondBuild)` will be empty/undefined.